# Trying to compile the Microsoft as-is provided .NET source code, getting hundreds of errors

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio

I downloaded Microsoft .NET 4.5.1 from https://referencesource.microsoft.com/,
tried to build it in visual studio using the provided ndp.sln solution, and got about 600 errors and 400 warnings.  Is this resource not actually for compilation?  If so, is there a microsoft .NET source project that is compilable?

Comment: From the download page "The archive includes a solution and project files that can be opened in Visual Studio. This solution will not build because it is missing crucial components such as resources, XAML files, etc. but it will be sufficient to browse the source code inside Visual Studio."

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reference source is not compilable (that's why it's called *reference* source); it's missing lots of internal resources and build steps.

You're looking for [.Net Core](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx), which is.

Comment: Just to clarify, would I be able to build the .NET reference code based on the output of a .NET core compilation?  I'm trying to get a DLL for `System.Data.Linq` built, which contains the `DataContext` class which I'd like to mess around with for my own purposes. `System.Data.Linq` is not in .NET core.

Comment: @IanRay impossible and forget about that crazy idea.